# Latency vs Duration: Interpreting Firefox's Web Developer Tools's Metrics

Tags: web, firefox, latency, web-developer-toolbar

What's the difference among these three fields (please check the attached snapshot)?

1. Latency
2. Duration

[Sample durations (20-30s) and latencies (between 1-5s)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2h8e.png)

End user experience on the browser is matching with duration meaning more than 20 seconds delay is being felt. Then what is latency representing?

Answer (score 3):

From the [notes in the sources](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/default/devtools/client/locales/en-US/netmonitor.properties#l648) of Firefox devtools :

> **Start Time** is the time from start of 1st request until the start of this request.

> **End Time** is the time from start of 1st request until the end of this response.

> **Latency** is the time from end of this request until the beginning of download of this response.

> **Response Time** is the time from start of 1st request until the beginning of download of this response.

> **Duration** is the time from start of this request until the end of this response.

A detailed breakdown of values used to calculate these numbers is available in the [Network Timings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Performance/Understanding_latency#network_timings) tab in the request details pane.